# WebStorm and TypeScript: how to navigate to JS source file of a package?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

Say that in my TypeScript project, I use Express and a method like this:

```
response.send('Hello');
```

I want to look how the `send()` method is implemented. However, when I ctrl+click the method name in WebStorm, it takes me to a `.d.ts` file (TypeScript definitions) instead of the real source. Understandably but a bit unpleasantly. What's the easiest way to get to the source?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution to that?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get to the source is disabling the corresponding library (if `d.ts` files were downloaded as a library)/removing typescript definitions from project. Then WebStorm will try to find the definition in .js files.

There is a feature request for a possibility to 'merge' TypeScript definitions with available `.js` definitions, using `d.ts` for completion and `.js` - for navigation ([WEB-12630](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12630)). The only problem here is that WebStorm can't always find the correct definition in `.js` - and that's the reason for using TypeScript definitions instead. For example, if the module properties are defined by iterating files in file system:

```
fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/middleware').forEach(function(filename){
  if (!/\.js$/.test(filename)) return;
  var name = basename(filename, '.js');
  function load(){ return require('./middleware/' + name); }
  exports.middleware.__defineGetter__(name, load);
  exports.__defineGetter__(name, load);
});
```

Resolving them for completion/navigation doesn't seem to be possible