# WebStorm & TypeScript: how to navigate to *.ts instead of *.d.ts

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

When using WebStorm / PhpStorm / IntelliJ IDEA...

When I navigate to a file it always pulls up the `*.d.ts` type definition file instead of the source `*.ts`

**How can I go right to the source `*.ts`?**

I tried marking the `*.d.ts` files as text, or registering the `*.d.ts` pattern under the "Text" file type.  The icons change on these files but the navigation still ends up on the `*.d.ts` file.

If I include `*.d.ts` under the file types to ignore (in Settings), they won't get recognized for things like version control -- I just want to affect navigation.

This seems like it would be a problem that would affect ALL typescript users... **what am I missing?**

See: [Related but different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787556/webstorm-and-typescript-how-to-navigate-to-js-source-file-of-a-package) (I want `*.ts` not `*.js`)

.

**UPDATE (Mar-20-2017):**

As of **WebStorm 2017.1**, registering the `*.d.ts` pattern under the "Text" file type **WORKS** for me.  Problem solved!

.

Comment: Related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22144, please upvote.

Comment: lena is right -- WEB-23618 is more generic which is more of what I'm looking for.  WEB-22144 is Angular specific

Comment: WEB-23618 is closed. New issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49438, please upvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE (Mar-20-2017):**

As of **WebStorm 2017.1**, registering the `*.d.ts` pattern under the "Text" file type **WORKS** for me (Settings/Editor/File Types). Problem solved!

Comment: is it the reason for downvoating the answer?

Comment: @lena This is a valid solution to the question.  Your answer is helpful but does not solve anything.  But I'm confused because I did not downvote your answer, I UPvoted your answer!

Comment: `*.d.ts` files are useful. You should not "ignore" them (considering them as Text).

Answer (score 6):

Please vote for [WEB-23618](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23618) to be notified on any progress

Comment: No - unless you need  specific support for navigating to  `@angular` core sources.  WEB-22144 requires downloading `@angular` sources locally and navigating to then from your Angular2 code. Once implemented, it will be a part of angular2 suppoirt, and won't be available in non-Angular projects.  WEB-23618 is far more generic, it is about navigating to .ts rather than d.ts if both are present. If you need this feature specially for Angular2 core methods, you should have mentioned this in your question. clearly you didn't do this. Will you edit your question accordingly?

Comment: You are correct and I am mistaken, WEB-23618 is more on point.  My question stands as is.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28729 is the more up-to-date version of this issue

Answer (score 1):

> When I navigate to a file it always pulls up the *.d.ts type definition file instead of the source *.ts

Libraries normally ship with `.js` + `.d.ts` right next to each other. They may or may not ship with the source `.ts` files.

To find the ts files you need to see the library's `node_modules/library/src` or something like that. It may be there or might be `.npmignore`d. Best thing to do is lookup the library on github / or whereever it is published from

Comment: I'm talking about within my own projects, i.e., when developing libraries.  I have all 3 files present but when I nav I expect it to go to the *.ts.

Comment: aha. So, @basarat's answer is wrong because it refers to libraries. But mine is wrong because it doesn't?

Comment: I see what you mean now

Comment: "Best thing to do is lookup the library on github / or whereever it is published from" Beg to differ.. The best thing would be to have navigation that works in this situation.